# Mock public methods of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

Inside of a Jest test I want to mock a specific function of a child component that is called with a ref. For example, something like:

```js
const mockedFn = jest.fn();
Child.prototype.functionToMock = mockedFn;
const wrapper = mount(<Parent/>);
wrapper.find(Button).simulate("click");
expect(mockedFn).toBeCalled();
```

where the parent component looks something like:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    private child: RefObject<Canvas> = React.createRef();
    ...
    render() {
        ...
        <Button onClick={this.onButtonClick}/>
        <Child ref={this.child}/>
    }

    private onButtonClick = () => {
        ...
        this.child.current.functionToMock();
    }
}
```

and the child component looks something like:

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
    ...

    public functionToMock = () => {
        ...
    }
}
```

I can't mock out the entire `Child` component, as there are other tests depending on some of the functionality contained within `Child`. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for posterity:

```js
const mockedFn = jest.fn();
const wrapper = mount(<Parent/>);
wrapper.update();
const child = wrapper.find(Child).instance() as Child;
child.functionToMock = mockedFn;
wrapper.find(Button).simulate("click");
expect(mockedFn).toBeCalled();
```